# Swift2 override of highlighted/selected doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm creating a custom UIButton class and i'm trying to override the highlighted/selected methods but they aren't called. After a bit of searching i found that this code should be working:

```
override var highlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        if highlighted {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
    }
}
```

I did the same for selected. I also tried using willSet but no luck. I'm using swift2.0. Could that make the difference? Anyone knows why it isn't called?

Comment: Thought so too... It is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. Due to the fact that i'm wokrking on an SDK shared library, I had to define the Module of my view controller and the Module of my button class. Once I did those, everything was working fluently.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this all wrong. No need to subclass. Just call `setBackgroundImage:forState:` with a black image for one state and a white image for the other.